# What is the best way to store and SOQL a junction sObject where multiple conditions need to be met?

Tags: soql, query, apex, junction-object, set

Not sure of the best way to phrase that question, so it might be easier to describe my current solution and then explain why I am looking for a better one.

So, I have an sObject called "Investment__c".

And when the user collects some Investments, other investments will become available to the user.

Sometimes, the user only requires one Investment for the next to become available, so this is easily handled by having a junction object with to fields, one looking up the required Investment and the other looking up the Enabled Investment.  Then I can simply do a query like:

```
SELECT enabled_investment__c 
FROM   Investment_Requirement__C
WHERE required_investment__c IN : possessedInvestmentIdSet
```

The problem is, that some Investments have multiple requirements.

If/as I store these additional requirements in additional records, if the User possesses at least one of these, he/she will get back the same result (e.g. this is operating as an OR instead of the desired AND).

What I really want is to make a query like this:

```
SELECT enabled_investment__c 
FROM   Investment_Requirement__C
WHERE (required_investment__c IN : possessedInvestmentIdSet)
AND ( 
           //  if enabled_investment__c is not unique, all corresponding 
          //  required_investment__c are also IN : possessedInvestmentIdSet  
        )
```

Since I'm not aware of any such functionality, instead I added a Text field ('additional_required_investments__c') which is also retrieved during the query.

This field contains a list of Investment__c Id, separated by semi-colons. which then can be checked in Apex after the query.  But for this to work, this information then needs to be transcribed manually multiple times for each Investment__c with multiple requirements.

As I'm not a fan of storing redundant information and otherwise this process seems inefficient, can anyone suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

So since you are already storing the Required investments in the Junction Object I am assuming that if it is not unique that you have other records in the Junction Object with the required investment but related to other held Investments.

If so you can do this work via apex and save the manual entry in the text field...

Do your first query to get the required from the possessed:

```
SELECT enabled_investment__c 
FROM   Investment_Requirement__C
WHERE required_investment__c IN : possessedInvestmentIdSet
```

The cycle through them and get a `Set<ID>` of Enabled_Investment

```
Set<ID> enabled_invest = New Set<ID>();
for(Investment_Requirement__c ir : YOURLIST){
     enabled_invest.add(ir.enabled_investment__c);
}
```

Then build a list of restricted investments that are not unique and have other requirements that are not possessed. Then you can cycle through your final list and remove these from that list

```
Investment_Requirement__c[] restricted_invest = [Select enabled_Investment__c, required_investment__c From Investment_Requirement__c where enabled_investment__c IN :enabled_invest AND ID NOT IN :YOURINITIALLIST AND required_invest__c NOT IN : possessedInvestmentIdSet];
```

Comment: Very good thinking... I like it... Waiting to see if anyone can suggest anything which doesn't include a second SOQL query before I accept it.  (The governor isn't threatening me yet, I'm just always thinking about it.)